# Implement sound Interval Arithmetic

Tags: java, double, precision, intervals, rounding

How to implement sound Interval Arithmetic in Java?

I need to implement a sound interval arithmetic with java.
Let's take the type *double* as example, we use an iterval [**0.09999....005**, **0.1000000...05**] to describe the value range information of the value "**0.1**", because the "**0.1**" cannot be strictly represented by IEEE-754 standard, namely *double* type in java.
When considering the operation **0.1 * 0.1**, the practical result may be **0.01000...5**, or **0.00999..5** within different rounding modes. The interval arithmetic result should be [*leftHand*, *rightHand*], and the *leftHand* should be less than **0.01000...5**, the rightHand should more than **0.00999..5**. 
When I use the type double to implememnt this arithmetic, I meet two questions:

1. When calculate the left-hand of the interval, I want to set the rounding mode to the DOWN, so that the left-hand value is less than the practical value. Namely, I need to calculate a number with ***doule*** type which is less than the practical value and a number with ***double*** type which is more than the practical value. We call this interval arithmetical sound.
2. I need a function to calculate the maximum in four ***double*** numbers.Namely,
   double **MAX**(*d1, d2, d3, d4*), ***return*** the maximum double number in the d1,d2,d3 and d4.

Comment: If you've reached the edge of the double type's useful limits, you may need to switch to using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: And ..what is your question?

Comment: If you're looking how to make use of all nice features IEEE754 defines (rounding, traps etc.), stop looking. Java (as almost any high-level language) doesnt give you access to it.